# Check if the sequence is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Check if the sequence $a_n=\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2-\frac{1}{k})^k}$ is convergent?
How to do this?

Comment: May be using the fact that $(2-\frac 1k) \lt 2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a_n=\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2-\frac{1}{k})^k}<\sqrt[n]{n2^n}=2\sqrt[n]{n}$$

Since $\sqrt[n]{n}\rightarrow 1$ and $a_n$ is bounded from below, it follows that the sequence converges and the limit is at most $2$. (Numerical evidence suggests that the limit is *exactly* $2$.)

***Edit:*** *Strictly speaking, it is not enough to know that the sequence is bounded from below because the upper bound is $2$ and in principle it is possible for the sequence to e.g. oscillate in the interval $[0,2]$. It should be easy to show that this is not the case though.*

Comment: Don't you need some kind of monotonicity to conclude convergence? You only have shouwn boundedness.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: I just realized the same thing and edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Upper bound:
$$
a_n<\Bigl(\sum_{k=1}^n2^k\Bigr)^{1/n}=(2^{n+1}-2)^{1/n}<2^{1+1/n}.
$$
Lower bound:
$$
a_n>\Biggl(\Bigl(2-\frac1n\Bigr)^n\Biggr)^{1/n}=2-\frac1n.
$$
Thus
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=2.
$$